# Error: invalid_client no registered origin

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have installed the Google Drive Realtime API sample files on my web server, following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart), including generating a client_id in the Cloud Console and inserting it into the `index.html` file.

When I visit that page and click the button to authorize the app, it pops up with a new window and shows:

> **Error: invalid_client**
>   no registered origin

The Request Details are:

```
openid_connect_request=true
cookie_policy_enforce=false
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
response_type=token
access_type=online
redirect_uri=postmessage
proxy=oauth2relay865404532
origin=http://mywebsite.com
state=264939258|0.165356673
display=page
client_id=1077585001321.apps.googleusercontent.com
authuser=0
```

I can't see any other client_id that I should be using in the Cloud Console. Does anybody know how to overcome this error? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In the new Google API Console, configure your OAuth2.0 authorized origins from

```
Your Project > APIs & auth > Credentials
```

You might need to add a new Client ID specifically for a web application (I did because the default was for AppEngine)

```
Create Client ID > Web Application > Authorized Javascript origins
```

If you are running on a local dev server, just add the exact URL such as :

```
http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

Comment: I would like to know about 'how to enter the localhost url for Authorized JavaScript origins'.since I was working on localhost machine and after entering the localhost url as 'http:127.0.0.1/myProjectName' it throws 'Origin URIs must not contain a path: http://127.0.0.1/myProjectName/'

Comment: You would just say 'http://localhost:13091' (whatever your localhost is) without mentioning your project name - worked for me! Thanks for this answer!

Comment: in case it helps at all - 
I had trouble following the above instructions.

the problem for me was that in the OAuth credential config, the field "Authorized JavaScript origins" was not set.

I set it to match the exact dev URL:
"http://127.0.0.1:8080"

I guess when you deploy to a real web server, you need to make a new client Id with the appropriate URL

Comment: It seems it takes time for the google to apply these settings - at least when adding additional origin - it was giving not-a-valid-origin error for 5-10 min before finally accepting it

Answer (score 14):

UPDATE: I changed accepted answer to Johno Scott instead as he refers to the newer version of the console, whereas mine was only true for the older version.

---

I solved it. I needed to enter a **WEB ORIGIN** on the OAuth 2.0 Client ID screen. Specifically, it had to be the exact path/url of the `index.html` file, otherwise it defaults to the root domain which doesn't work.

This screenshot shows you exactly where it needs to be entered:

[image]