# invalid_client no registered origin for service account approach

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to do Google API authorization through both Web Application approach and service account approach. For web application approach, the quick start code from their website works fine. However when I tried the same code with service account Client ID (same code as the quick start example, just replacing the Client ID), it gives me Invalid_client no registered origin error.

I saw in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633590/error-invalid-client-no-registered-origin) and other SO questions, mostly they forgot to put the Authorized Javascript Origin. However, this is different for service account approach, they don't have this field.

Anyone encountered same issue?

> Error message: no registered origin
>
> Request Details proxy=oauth2relay1086088613 
>  immediate=false 
>   scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly
>   origin=https://localhost:9443
>  response_type=token
>   redirect_uri=postmessage
>  state=909080772|0.2369183797
>   client_id=113356969233986791514
>  include_granted_scopes=true

Answer (score 0):

Service accounts are typically used in server-to-server communication. You can think of a service account as a robot user that has permissions to access the API. Unless you're doing domain-wide delegation (where a service account can act on behalf of all users on a domain), you probably just want to use OAuth. Perhaps try [the credentials wizard](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/credentials/wizard) and see what it recommends?

If you do end up wanting to use service accounts, you'll need to download a private key for the service account and sign the request with that key (rather than just including the OAuth client ID). To do that, I recommend using one of the [Google API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries?hl=en).